# Set wireless network as preferential

Tags: wireless, networking

I have a problem I'm not sure how to (or even if it's possible to) solve in Linux (I'm using Ubuntu).

I need to make sure that, if there are two or more available wireless networks I have access to, Linux will always connect to Network-X.

What happens to me is that Linux connects to the one with the strongest signal or to the one that fulfills the criteria it things is better, exactly what I don't want.

Basically, if Network-X is available, always connect to Network-X.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the upper right corner click on the Network symbol and open *Edit Connections...*

[image]

There choose the Wireless network you don't want to connect to and click *Edit*

[image]

In there you should open the *General*

[image]

Uncheck the first box like this:

[image]

Repeat that for the other Wireles-Networks and leave the Wireless-Network you want to automatically connect to checked. (like in Picture 3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr Seed, but it's not exactly what I asked. I'll try to explain a little better.

I have access to fon.com so, I can see their network everywhere of my city and I want my network to automatically connect to FON networks when they are available.

In my home I'll have FON network available but also my own network. Ubuntu will always connect to FON network in my home instead my own network so, I want to make sure my own network is always chosen if I have at the same time more than one network I have access.